# "Crooked" end of d3.js area graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I'm trying to make an area graph that matches a line graph (using identical data) up to an arbitrary horizontal point on the graph. Here's how I've set up the area graph:

```
    var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y0(each_graph_height)
    .y1(function(d,i) {
        if (i <= this_week_number) {
            return y(d);
        } else {
            return each_graph_height;
        }               
    });
```

However, the right edge of the area graph is "crooked". Here is what it looks like:

[image: crooked graph]

Any ideas why, and what I can do to make the area graph end with a perfect vertical edge?

Comment: Looks like you've got a data point at y=0 at the end of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to use the data points up until "this_week_number", and for all weeks after that to use y=0.  But the x values still keep on increasing, so you have a zero-width area extending to the end of your axis.  And you still have a line drawn from this week's (x,y) data point to next week's (x, 0) data point.

To actually crop off the area, you need to crop off the x values as well as the y values:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d,i) {
    if (i <= this_week_number) {
        return x(d);
    } else {
        return x(this_week_number);
    }               
})
.y0(each_graph_height)
.y1(function(d,i) {
    if (i <= this_week_number) {
        return y(d);
    } else {
        return each_graph_height;
    }               
});
```

That should work, (you'll just have an accumulation of points all at the same point on the axis), but a more elegant solution would be to use a `defined` function to actually cut out the extra data points:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x( function(d,i) { return x(i); } )
.y0( each_graph_height )
.y1( function(d,i) { return y(d); } )
.defined( function(d,i){ return i <= this_week_number; } );
```

([See this Mike Bostock example for a more conventional use of the defined method](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090))

Comment: Perfect! Great introduction to area.defined(). [Documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area_defined) for anyone else who wants the details.